# Spring Security simple login page cant login

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, thymeleaf

So I am trying to creating simple Login Page with help of the Spring Boot and Security. So what I currently have is custom login page and in memory authentication with one user and role.
The problem is that when I am entering proper user/password spirng is not authenticating it as valid data, and redirecting me again to login page, but this time with: `/login#error`

On client side I am using thymeleaf.

form snippet:

```
<form th:action="@{/perform_login}" method="post">
    <input name="user" placeholder="Username" /> <br /> 
    <input name="pass" placeholder="Password" /> <br /> 
    <input type="submit" value="Login" />
</form>
```

Configuration class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()//
            .withUser("root").password("root").roles("USER");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests() //
                .antMatchers("/").hasRole("USER") //
                .antMatchers("/login*").permitAll().and() //
                .formLogin() //
                .loginPage("/login")//
                .loginProcessingUrl("/perform_login")//
                .and()//
                .logout()//
                .permitAll();
    }

}
```

And controller is simple

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/login")
public class LoginController {

    @GetMapping
    public String getLoginPage() {
        return "login";
    }
}
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring Security - Authentication not working even the credentials are correct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36970359/spring-security-authentication-not-working-even-the-credentials-are-correct)

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40321085/springs-userdetailsservice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way (for me) is to make a `@Bean` and use `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` and implement `WebMvcConfigurer` to configure everything with few steps. This is the smallest example ever made:

```
@Configuration
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Controller
    public class HomeController {

        @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public String home(Model model, Authentication authentication, Principal principal) {
            if (authentication == null) {
                return "forward:/login";
            } else {
                model.addAttribute("user", principal.getName());
                return "home";
            }
        }
    }

    @Bean
    public WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter webSecurityConfig() {
        return new WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter() {
            @Override
            protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
                http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                        .and().formLogin().loginPage("/login")
                        .defaultSuccessUrl("/")
                        .permitAll()
                        .and().logout().permitAll();
                http.headers().frameOptions().disable();
            }

            @Override
            protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder builder) throws Exception {
                builder.authenticationProvider(new AuthenticationProvider() {
                    @Override
                    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
                        String username = authentication.getName();
                        String password = authentication.getCredentials().toString();
                        if (username.equals("username") && password.equals("password")) {
                            List<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorities = new ArrayList<>();
                            grantedAuthorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER"));
                            return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, password, grantedAuthorities);
                        }
                        throw new AuthenticationServiceException("Invalid credentials.");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
                        return authentication.equals(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class);
                    }
                });
            }
        };
    }

    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/home").setViewName("home");
        registry.addViewController("/login").setViewName("login");
    }
}
```

You said that you are using `thymeleaf` so lets say your `login.html` form will be something like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title>login example</title>
</head>
<body>
<form th:action="@{/login}" method="post">
    <input name="username" placeholder="Username"/> <br/>
    <input name="password" placeholder="Password"/> <br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Login"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

And the `home.html` page when you are logged in:

```
<!doctype html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title>home page</title>
</head>
<body>
Hello, <span th:text="${user}"></span><br>
<a href="/logout"> sign out</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I will mark this as accepted answer. But the real issue was that I set name for inputs `user` and `pass` and it need to be set as `username` and `password`.